# Find numbers of weeks in date range(from date-To date) in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two dates `FromDate` and `ToDate`. Start is always **Monday** and `ToDate` is always **Friday**.

- I want to find number of weeks separately not just count.
- I want to show week1, week2, week3, etc report in given date range. (ie Weekly product counts).

I have tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM WeekDate
WHERE DATEDIFF(Week,GETDATE(),'2013-09-20')=0
```

It gives all values not just for week 0.
Can any one help me about this?

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeekDate]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Counter] [int] NULL,
    [CDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and data is

```
1   1   2013-09-17 00:00:00.000 
3   2   2013-09-18 00:00:00.000 
4   6   2013-09-19 00:00:00.000 
5   2   2013-09-23 00:00:00.000 
6   3   2013-09-24 00:00:00.000 
7   4   2013-10-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Please include more information on table structure and an example of the expected result.

Comment: please include your data and desired output

Comment: "It gives all values" - of course it does. Look at your `WHERE` clause again, and notice that you're not referencing *any* columns. The `WHERE` clause is a constant expression, and can only be true (returning all rows) or false (returning no rows)

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WeekDate](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Counter] [int] NULL,
 [CDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] and data is 1 1 2013-09-17 00:00:00.000
3 2 2013-09-18 00:00:00.000
4 6 2013-09-19 00:00:00.000
5 2 2013-09-23 00:00:00.000
6 3 2013-09-24 00:00:00.000
7 4 2013-10-01 00:00:00.000 i wnat to get Sum of Count on weekly basis. i just send Fromdate and Todate as parameter.

Comment: you are always getting 0, since you using `GETDATE()` and a date constant that happens to be in the same week.

`SELECT * FROM WeekDate
WHERE DATEDIFF(Week,FromDate,ToDate)=0`

Comment: Ah may be you want this: `select count(*), datediff(Week,FromDate,ToDate) as ddiff from WeekDate group by datediff(Week,FromDate,ToDate)`. Hard to say without data...

Comment: If you're attempting to post a table definition in response to JNF, **please** use the edit link below your question and the `{}` button to format it. You can't format it in the comments section and it'll be unreadable.

Comment: what are you considering as your datefirst ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without example of output, but could be something like this:

```
select
    sum(Counter),
    datediff(day, @FromDate, CDate) / 7 as ddiff
from WeekDate
-- if you need to filter out rows
where CDate >= @FromDate and CDate <= @ToDate
group by datediff(day, @FromDate, CDate) / 7
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0714f/4)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

I think you want sum of product by weekly and if so then try this as you said i have taken start date as **Monday** and end date as **Friday**

```
declare @StartDate datetime,
        @EndDate datetime;

select  @StartDate = '2013-09-16',
        @EndDate = '2013-10-04';

;with cte as
(
  select @StartDate StartDate, 
    DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @StartDate), 6) EndDate
  union all
  select dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate),
    dateadd(ww, 1, EndDate)
  from cte
  where dateadd(ww, 1, StartDate)<=  @EndDate
)
select (Select COUNT(Cdate) from WeekDate where Cdate between StartDate and EndDate) count1 , StartDate , EndDate
from cte
```